# "Appeal from a decision"

Tags: prepositions

This sentence from a wiki page of a court case grates. I have always seen/heard *appeal a decision* or *appeal **against** a ruling*. What does **appeal from** mean?

> Tiffany appealed **from** these decisions to the Second Circuit. ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiffany_(NJ)_Inc._v._eBay_Inc.))

Answer (score 1):

The grammar in that sentence is incorrect. You *appeal a ruling*, or *appeal a decision* as you mentioned. (You don't *appeal from*.)

Comment: And yet, strangely, a check on Google Books Ngram Viewer reveals **appeal from..** to be roughly twice as popular as just **appeal**. I was astonished! https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=appeal+a+decision%2Cappeal+from+a+decision

Comment: @RonaldSole That IS surprising! I looked through a few of the snippets there and certainly *some* slightly different senses being used, i.e. where the appeal is described legalistically as being "taken from" a decision, which feels rather technical and lawyerly to me. That said, there are also examples that seem to be mostly in line with the OP's sense here. It sounds very wrong to my layman's ears, but I guess I won't edit the wikipedia page on that basis.

Comment: We're on the same side. The inclusion of **from** sounds utterly foreign to my ears too.

Comment: +1 It seems someone has gone out of their way to correct the sentence on the Wiki page since I posted.